# Difference between as and foreignKey when defining belongsTo relationship in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Consider the following snippet from [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#foreign-keys)

```
class User extends Model {}
User.init({/* attributes */}, { sequelize, modelName: 'user' })
class UserRole extends Model {}
UserRole.init({/* attributes */}, { sequelize, modelName: 'userRole' });
```

What is the difference between

```
User.belongsTo(UserRole, {as: 'role'}); // Adds roleId to user rather than userRoleId to User
```

and

```
User.belongsTo(UserRole, {foreignKey: 'roleId'}); // Adds roleId to user rather than userRoleId to User
```

And why someone would write

```
User.belongsTo(UserRole, {foreignKey: 'roleId', as: 'fk_user_role'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User.belongsTo(UserRole, {foreignKey: 'roleId', as: 'fk_user_role'});
```

**as: 'fk_user_role'** is used as an alias to distinguish associations of a certain model with another model that is made more then one time.
For instance:

```
User.belongsTo(Organization, {foreignKey: 'organizationId', as: 'Organization'});
User.belongsTo(Organization, {foreignKey: 'headOrganizationId', as: 'HeadOrganization'});
...
User.findOne({
where: { 
  id: userId
},
include: [{
  model: Organization,
  as: 'Organization'
}, {
  model: Organization,
  as: 'HeadOrganization'
}]
})
```

and you'll get an user object with Organization and HeadOrganization props.